# How to delete a kdb partitioned table contents?

Tags: kdb

I wrote a q script to create a partitioned table and insert rows from a large kdb file I previously saved. The script only saves data for a specific date that I pass in from the command line.

How can I clear the contents of the partitioned table at the begin of the script? Or more in general, how can I insure the table contents are not duplicated if I run the script more than once?

Comment: If your script is using `.Q.dpft[]` to write to each partition, then you do not need to worry about duplication: the function overwrites any existing data in the table for that date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going to assume your partitioned by date, so directory structure:

```
2012.04.03
          /trade
2012.04.04
          /trade
2012.04.05
          /trade
                /ticker
                /price
                /size
```

1. To clear the contents for one date simply delete that folder and then `\l`.
2. To prevent duplicating check if any data first exists for that date:

   `select count i from trade where date=2012.04.06`

If one dates data may come from different files that makes it trickier. You may want to add a sourceFile column and or as a separate table to keep track of which files were loaded.

Comment: What do you mean by "and then \|"?

Comment: He means you must re-map the table in order to see the changes. See http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:KdbplusForMortals/partitioned_tables#1.3.5_Modifying_Partitioned_Tables

Comment: @RobertKubrick it's `\l`, btw, not `\|`

Answer (score 1):

You can also incorporate the deletion process in a q function.
Say the location you write is in the format:

```
/hdb/date/tablename/colname

q) db1:"/hdb/date";    / you can pass this as a argument in a function

q) deletedb:{[dbname] systemcmd: "rm -rfv ",dbdelete; system systemcmd}

q) deletedb db1
```